# webpack compiled successfully, but http://localhost:8080/ returns 404 error

Tags: html, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, sass-loader

I installed npm:
webpack
webpack-cli
css-loader
node-sass
sass
sass-loader
style-loader
mini-css-extract-plugin

And received:
404 error on http://localhost:8080
Cannot GET /

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "landing-dlmr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.json:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'js/main.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,

          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",

          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: 'css/main.css',
      })
  ],
  watch: true
};
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dellmayer</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.scss"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body class="page__body">
    <header class="header">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="menu__list">
          <li class="menu__item">HOME</li>
          <li class="menu__item">HISTORY</li>
          <li class="menu__item">PRODUCT</li>
          <li class="menu__item">SPECIFICATION</li>
          <li class="menu__item">IN THE BOX</li>
          <li class="menu__item">CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index/js:

```
import './styles/main.scss';
```

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8coL.png)
[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rfz6.png)

I can just open index.html directly in browser with implemented styles, but can't see the localhost

Answer (score 0):

- See [Recommended](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/#recommended)

> For development mode (including `webpack-dev-server`) you can use `style-loader`, because it injects CSS into the DOM using multiple and works faster.

- Follow the [Using webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-webpack-dev-server) documentation
- Use `html-webpack-plugin` to inject the JS script and CSS style tag to the HTML template.

E.g.

project structure:

```bash
✗ tree -L 2 -I node_modules
.
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.js
│   └── style.scss
└── webpack.config.js

1 directory, 6 files
```

`src/index.js`：

```js
import './style.scss'
```

`src/style.scss`:

```scss
.menu__item {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

`src/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Dellmayer</title>
</head>

<body class="page__body">
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="menu__list">
        <li class="menu__item">HOME</li>
        <li class="menu__item">HISTORY</li>
        <li class="menu__item">PRODUCT</li>
        <li class="menu__item">SPECIFICATION</li>
        <li class="menu__item">IN THE BOX</li>
        <li class="menu__item">CONTACT</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack serve"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "sass": "^1.66.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  }
}
```

Build logs:

```bash
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://192.168.54.78:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from './dist' directory
asset js/main.js 292 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset index.html 642 bytes [emitted]
runtime modules 30.3 KiB 15 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 186 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 71.8 KiB 16 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.84 KiB 6 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 5.3 KiB 4 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 81.8 KiB 4 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 2.31 KiB
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/noSourceMaps.js 64 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js 2.25 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/ansi-html-community/index.js 4.16 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/events/events.js 14.5 KiB [built] [code generated]
modules by path ./src/ 2.83 KiB
  ./src/index.js 22 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./src/style.scss 2.36 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/style.scss 462 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 442 ms
```

[image]